# Create a object of maps from list and a map

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have these locals

```
vpc_peering = {
  require_dms = 1
  vpc = [
    {
      id     = "vpc-ai"
      owner  = "a"
      cidr   = "10.25.0.0/16"
      name   = "m-development"
      region = "ap-southeast-2"
    }
 ]} 
route_table_ids = [1, 2]
}
```

And want to combine them to produce an object/map with this format

```
vpc_peering_routes = {
  1-vpc-ai = {
    id     = "vpc-ai"
    owner  = "a"
    cidr   = "10.25.0.0/16"
    name   = "m-development"
    region = "ap-southeast-2"
    route_table_id = 1
  }
  2-vpc-ai = {
    id     = "vpc-ai"
    owner  = "a"
    cidr   = "10.25.0.0/16"
    name   = "m-development"
    region = "ap-southeast-2"
    route_table_id = 2
  }
}
```

So that I can use it for adding all cidrs to the aws_route

```
resource "aws_route" "vpc_peering_private_routes" {
  for_each = local.vpc_peering_routes
   
  route_table_id            = each.value.route_table_id
  destination_cidr_block = each.value.cidr
  vpc_peering_connection_id = aws_vpc_peering_connection.vpc_peering.id
}
```

I have tried different merge and maps but I always end up with a nested map

Any examples would be great :)

EDIT found the solution

```
route_table_cidr_combination = setproduct(local.route_table_ids, local.vpc_peering.vpc)
vpc_peering_cidr_routes = {
   for item in local.route_table_cidr_combination :  "${item[0]}-${item[1].id}" => merge(item[1], {route_table_id = item[0]})
}
```

Comment: if you solved your question then it is best to use the content as an answer, and not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since I tested with local variables, here's a solution I have come up with:

```
locals {
  vpc_peering = {
    require_dms = 1
    vpc = [
      {
        id     = "vpc-ai"
        owner  = "a"
        cidr   = "10.25.0.0/16"
        name   = "m-development"
        region = "ap-southeast-2"
      }
  ] }

  route_table_ids = [1, 2]

  vpc_peering_routes = merge(flatten([
    for k, v in local.vpc_peering.vpc[*] : [
      for i in local.route_table_ids : {
        "${i}-${v.id}" = {
          "id"             = "${v.id}"
          "owner"          = "${v.owner}"
          "name"           = "${v.name}"
          "region"         = "${v.region}"
          "route_table_id" = "${i}"
        }
      }
    ]
  ])...)
}
```

This will give:

```
> local.vpc_peering_routes
{
  "1-vpc-ai" = {
    "id" = "vpc-ai"
    "name" = "m-development"
    "owner" = "a"
    "region" = "ap-southeast-2"
    "route_table_id" = 1
  }
  "2-vpc-ai" = {
    "id" = "vpc-ai"
    "name" = "m-development"
    "owner" = "a"
    "region" = "ap-southeast-2"
    "route_table_id" = 2
  }
}
```

The solution is using [`merge`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge) and [`flatten`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten) built-in functions as well as the ellipsis operator (`...`), so that is not a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code:

```
vpc_peering_routes = merge([
    for r in local.route_table_ids :
    {
      for k, v in local.vpc_peering.vpc : "${r}-${v.id}" => merge(v, { route_table_id = r })
    }
  ]...)
```